# Scripts Optimization in NG Build --prod resulting in a blank screen during Firebase Deploy/Serve

Tags: angular, firebase

I have been working on getting my Angular9 app to properly deploy using Firebase. When using the --prod tag in ng build, the firebase deploy/serve commands resulted in a blank screen. The files were retrieved properly in the dist/projectname folder when checking the network tab of dev tools on Chrome. The app only loaded successfully when I did not use the --prod tag in running "ng build". After modifying some values within the Angular.json file, I noticed that disabling the scripts optimization during the --prod build resulted in a successful load during firebase deploy/serve. My question is what occurs during that script optimization process that might be causing this issue.

Here is my Angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "customer-portal": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/customer-portal",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "dist/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.js",
              "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf.worker.js",
              "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/viewer.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": {"scripts" : false, "styles": true},
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "20mb",
                  "maximumError": "20mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "10kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "customer-portal:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "customer-portal:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "customer-portal:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "customer-portal:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "customer-portal:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "customer-portal"
}
```

Any info would be appreciated. Thank you!